# Expansion of $(x+h)^n$

Tags: derivatives, proof-explanation

I was reading the proof for the power rule for derivatives, and I came across this step:

$\displaystyle \frac{\left({x + h}\right)^n - x^n} h = \displaystyle \frac{x^n} h \left({\left({1 + \frac h x}\right)^n - 1}\right)$

I was wondering if someone could elaborate on the inner workings of this step? They seem to have been able to expand $(x+h)^n$ without much trouble, and without the need for a sigma sum.

To clarify, I understand factorization, and how they extracted $\displaystyle \frac{x^n}h$, but everything before that is a haze.

For reference: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Power_Rule_for_Derivatives/Real_Number_Index/Proof_1

Comment: Just factor out $x^n$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic idea is to pull out a factor of $x^n$ in the numerator.  The rest is fairly straight-forward algebraic computation.
\begin{align} \frac{(x+h)^n - x^n}{h}
&= \frac{\left( x + \frac{x}{x} h \right)^n - x^n }{h} && (\text{multiply by 1}) \\
&= \frac{\left( x \left(1+\frac{h}{x}\right) \right)^n - x^n}{h} &&(\text{factor out $x$}) \\
&= \frac{x^n \left(1+\frac{h}{x}\right)^n - x^n}{h} && (\text{exponentiation rules}) \\
&= \frac{x^n \left( \left(1+\frac{h}{x}\right)^n - 1\right)}{h} && (\text{factor out $x^n$}) \\
&= \frac{x^n}{h} \left( \left(1+\frac{h}{x}\right)^n - 1\right). && (\text{simplify})
\end{align}

Answer (score 3):

**Big Hint:**$$\begin{align*}\left(x+h\right)^n-x^n & =\left[x\left(1+\frac hx\right)\right]^n-x^n\\ & =x^n\left(1+\frac hx\right)^n-x^n\end{align*}$$

Comment: Yep, perfect. Man, some times it's the little things that pass me by.

Comment: @Alec Lol don’t worry, happens to everybody sometimes.